# Executando dupla função não nomeada no ato de declaração da mesma

Tags: javascript

Estou "brincando" com Javascript e me deparei com uma dúvida. Eu entendo que, quando minha página HTML é carregada, se eu quiser já executar uma função sem que precise declarar a mesma, só tenho que definir esta função direta, assim:

```
(function(){console.log('foo');})();
```

Minha dúvida (porque não consegui fazer funcionar) é como eu possa executar uma dupla função na mesma declaração, algo parecido com isso (no meu entender):

```
(
  function(){
    var b = 'hello world!';
    console.log('bar');
  },
  function(b){
    console.log('foo ' + 'b'); //o "b" declarado anteriormente na 1ª função
  }
)();
```

existe algo assim? basicamente quero que tal função execute após a primeira mas, que essa segunda consuma o mesmo esforço do DOM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo que fosse possivel executar estas funções desta forma em batch, ainda teria um problema, uma variavel declarada dentro de uma visão é visivel apenas dentro da mesma, então neste caso a variavel `b` não estaria disponivel para a segunda função.

```
(
  function(){
    var b = 'hello world!';
    console.log('bar');
  },
  function(b){
    console.log('foo ' + 'b'); //o "b" declarado anteriormente na 1ª função
  }
)();
```

Neste caso a unica forma de executar estas 2 funções anonimas mantendo uma variavel compatilhada, é encapisulando as duas em uma terceita função anonima.

```js
(function() {
  var b;
  (function(){
    b = 'hello world!';    
  })();
  (function(){
    alert('foo ' + b);
  })();
})();
```

mas a unica utilidade deste tipo de contrução é poluir o codigo e sinceramente não vejo outra utilidade para IIFE (expressão de função com execução imediata) que não seja encapsular uma variavel em um closure e permitir que a mesma seja acessada apenas através de métodos.

```js
var contador = (function () {
  var indice = 0;

  return {
    get: function () { return indice; },
    set: function (value) { indice = value; },
    incrementar: function () { return ++indice; },
  }
})();

var log = document.getElementById("log");
log.innerHTML += "<div>indice: " + contador.get() + "</div>";
log.innerHTML += "<div>indice: " + contador.set(3) + "</div>";
log.innerHTML += "<div>indice: " + contador.get() + "</div>";
log.innerHTML += "<div>indice: " + contador.incrementar() + "</div>";
log.innerHTML += "<div>indice: " + contador.indice + "</div>";
```

```html
<div id="log">
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, fantástico isso... Estou estudando essas IIFE, detalhe que apenas tinha visto isso em alguns códigos na internet, nem nome eu sabia... Agora vou aprofundar hehe, obrigado!

Comment: @LeandroLUK, como eu disse, vejo pouco uso em IIFE, acabo preferindo definir uma "Classe", caso precise de alguma propriedade calculada ou somente leitura, uso Object.defineProperty, e para definir os métodos uso "Classe".prototype.

Comment: Sim em certos aspectos concordo plenamente, meu problema é que no meu caso estou constituindo um plugin para o chrome que irá manipular um site já criado, e estou testando métodos de não declarar elementos apenas reconfigurar o site como eu quero, rsrs

Comment: Você pode criar um handleEvent como o do segundo exemplo deste [LINK](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/handleevent). Neste caso o handleEvent vai funcionar como um closure para o seu plug-in (isolando o mesmo) e permitir organizar o seu código.

Answer (score 3):

Pode executar as função anonimas diretamente adicionando os dois *parenteses* *( )* no final de cada função. Elas serão executadas em um processo de fila. Segue o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/1gbx82tc/) e o exemplo a baixo.

```
(
  function(){
    var b = 'hello world!';
    console.log('bar');
  }(),
  function(b){
    console.log('foo ' + 'b');
  }()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser executar uma função logo no carregar da página, apenas remova o código da função e deixe-o solto no script. Como:

```
var b = 'hello world!';
console.log('bar');
console.log('foo ' + 'b');
```

Ou se precisa mesmo de uma função, simplesmente a invoque como:

```
function foofoo(){
    var b = 'hello world!';
    console.log('bar');
    return b;
}
function foobar(bar){
    console.log('foo ' + 'b'); 
}
bar = foofoo();
foobar(bar);
```

Pronto!

Comment: Minha dúvida é sobre a execução de funções não declaradas cara...